# Cannot accept/reject a call once initial invitation is rejected by the same user in azure communication service

Tags: javascript, angular, azure-communication-services

We have a call system that is developed under the Microsoft Teams where we have a bot in our end which determines available user and invites that user. We are trying to implement azure communication service to handle the call actions from our web application.
In our our system there is a feature where the call keeps searching for available user and re-routes the call even if it was rejected previously. On initial incoming request if user rejects the call it will work but if the same call is routed back to that user and when tries to accept or reject it then azure communication service throws *call cannot be accepted because call state is not "Notified".*

Are there any solutions for this scenario?

[image: On call accept after rejecting initial invitation]

[image: On call reject after rejecting initial invitation]

Comment: Can you provide any code samples?